# Cloud Functions: Transaction with FieldValue.increment() not running atomically

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Functions transaction that uses FieldValue.increment() to update a nested map, but it isn't running atomically, thus the value updates aren't accurate (running the transaction in quick succession results in an incorrect count).

The function is fired via:

```
export const updateCategoryAndSendMessage= functions.firestore.document('events/{any}').onUpdate((event, context) => {
```

which include the following transaction:

```
db.runTransaction(tx => {
    const categoryCounterRef = db.collection("data").doc("categoryCount")
    const intToIncrement = event.after.data().published == true ? 1 : -1;
    const location = event.after.data().location;

    await tx.get(categoryCounterRef).then(doc => {

        for (const key in event.after.data().category) {
            event.after.data().category[key].forEach(async (subCategory) => {
                const map = { [key]: { [subCategory]: FieldValue.increment(intToIncrement) } };
               await tx.set(categoryCounterRef, { [location]: map }, { merge: true })
            })
        }
    },
    ).then(result => {
        console.info('Transaction success!')
    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Transaction failure:', err)
        })
}).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

> Example:
>
> Value of field to increment: 0
>
> Tap on button that performs the function multiple times in quick succession (to switch between true and false for "Published")
>
> Expected value: 0 or 1 (depending on whether reference document value is true or false)
>
> Actual value: -3, 5, -2 etc.
>
> As far as I'm aware, transactions should be performed "first come, first served" to avoid inaccurate data. It seems like the function isn't "queuing up" correctly - for lack of a better word.

I'm a bit stumped, would greatly appreciate any guidance with this.

Comment: I don't think that error message has anything to do with your transaction.  If you do a google search on that message, you'll see others who had the same problem, but they're not working with transactions.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for that, I was able to solve the credentials issue (added link to solution). Unfortunately though, the transaction still isn't updating atomically

Comment: You might want to update the question to remove mention of the error that's now resolved (since it's no longer an issue), and instead focus on the details of your observations about the transaction.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sure, I have done so

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some specific details about what the function is actually doing, that's different that what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hopefully my edit makes a bit more sense?

Answer (score 2):

Oh goodness, I was missing return...

```
return db.runTransaction(tx => {
```

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html  might related [: